# Specific modules not Importing after cloning Git repository

Tags: 16.04, python3, git, github, virtualenv

So recently I cloned a repository SymPy by doing the following steps:

- Created Python3 virtual environment
- Activated it (from Terminal)
- Then ran git clone _sample_URL_

After that I ran the following to open up IDLE:

```
$ python -m idlelib
```

Then I ran the following commands:

```
>>> import sympy
```

No error, but after that I ran the following to import a module as given in this [documentation](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/guide.html):

```
from sympy.abc import x, y
```

it gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#8>", line 1, in <module>
    from sympy.abc import x, y
ImportError: No module named 'sympy.abc'
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you check that the sympy you are importing is the one you expect? Try `import sympy` then `sympy.__file__` and `sympy.__version__`

Comment: @match I'll try it tomorrow... But what do you mean by 'the one you expect' . Are you suggesting that it is importing from the main global python sympy? (Don't know the correct term)

Comment: Yes - to check that the `sympy` you are importing is the git cloned one and not a system-wide one.

Comment: @match but would it matter? I mean I don't expect it to be very different (in terms of version) so shouldn't it import fine?

Comment: @match i ran the commands in IDLE shell. It is saying no attribute in sympy named file and no attribute in sympy named version.

Comment: You are importing something called `sympy` that isn't the `sympy` module at all - maybe an empty file, or a directory with no python in it? If you don't mind exactly which sympy you use, then perhaps you would be better doing `pip install sympy` in your virtualenv instead of trying to use the latest from github?

Comment: @match I was going to my own modifications to it basically I forked it to my own GitHub...I have sympy in anaconda, but what do you suggest to do if you want to develop it?

Comment: @match thanks for the heads up...I think you are correct.

Comment: @match You were correct..earlier i was copying the entire directory when in reality i needed to copy only the sympy directory within the main sympy directory...if you write an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely that you are importing a `sympy` other than the one you intended.

You can debug which `sympy` you are importing using `sympy.__file__` and `sympy.__version__` which should give you more information on which one you are using, and help debug things.

If that doesn't work it might also be worth checking that the git repo has the appropriate files you'd expect in `sympy/` (e.g. `abc/` etc).

Alternatively if you aren't concerned with using the latest code form github, just do `pip install sympy` instead to get the latest version into your virtual environment.

Comment: I don't know whether you have developed using git or not but if you have can you answer a question? I downloaded sympy inside it was setup.Py and another sympy, now when I imported that another sympy by copy paste in another venv it ran fine, but for the current venv I had to run setup.py and everything went smoothly from there. My question is now if I write some new module and push it in GitHub will it be identical to the original? Or does anything change after running setup.py?

Comment: It all comes down to what `setup.py` contains - usually it is just enough to tell `pip` how to build and install a package - however it can also contain any arbitrary python code, so you need to read what else it does other than it's main `setup` method.